# Why is the grid current of this single-phase AC/DC rectifier not an AC sinusoidal waveform?

Tags: pwm, converter, single-phase

I drew a single-phase AC/DC rectifier in PLECS and used bipolar PWM to control it.

[image]

Here's my calculation process and related parameters (the duty cycle of Vtri is 0.5):

[image]

I think my calculation is correct, but the waveform of the grid current Is is not an AC sinusoidal waveform; it has a DC component.

[image]

I wonder what went wrong?

Comment: You have a capacitor on the output. Assuming the capacitor has been charged, no further current is needed to charge it. Depending on the load discharging the capacitor will determine what the input current waveform looks like. This is the problem that PFC (power factor correction) circuits solve in real world power supplies.

Comment: Yes, the initial capacitance value of the DC side capacitor is 500V. If I want to get the required current curve, do I need to change it to 550V?

Comment: Voltage rating isn’t the issue. In your simulation graph the DC voltage across the capacitor and DC current into the capacitor. This will demonstrate the load your bridge rectifier is driving. If your load was purely resistive, then your grid current would be sinusoidal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but rectifiers generally require capacitance to reduce the voltage ripple on the load, right? Without this capacitor, I find the grid current will also be distorted.  In addition, I am very sorry for my misexpression. I said that I set the initial voltage of 500 volts for this capacitor, and its initial voltage affects the grid current waveform. Should I set it to 0V or 550V?

Comment: @mikux111 Given your equations, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzc16.png) is what I get in LTspice. The bottom plot shows that there is a slight displacement between the voltage and current, but the voltage across the output is sinusoidal, not wavy, like yours, and I had to use the negative value of the angle you've calculated.

Comment: @a concerned citizen Thank you very much! When I set the initial voltage of the capacitor to 550V, the voltage across the output is sinusoidal. So does the initial voltage of the capacitor also affects the output of the rectifier and the grid current waveform?